# How to use multiple SettingsProviders

Tags: c#, application-settings, settingsprovider

Up until now I have always stored user settings in the registry but I'm attempting to start saving settings using the `ApplicationSettings`. On the surface things are pretty simple but I am having trouble creating nested groups.

I have several settings (in the User scope) which need to be different based on which customer the user is currently active.

For example I might load customer `Mr Bloggs` and the setting for `DefaultPrice` should be `12.34` but then I would change customer to `Mr Smith` and his `DefaultPrice` should be `22.90`.

I have tried using a custom `SettingsProvider` but was unable to refresh the settings when I changed customer. I have considered not using `ApplicationSettings` but don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is something easy I'm missing.

*I am using C#, .NET 4.0 Full & Visual Studio 2010.*
How can I resolve this issue?